# Network Error: 0x80070043 - The network name cannot be found. Trying to insert a new drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, network-shares

I'm using a 3-year-old computer - HP laptop, so I wanted to insert a new Windows 10 network drive on File Explorer, but the map network drive won't let me insert because the network name cannot be found (0x80070043).

The error message says:

1. Network Error (already connected)
2. Windows cannot access `Archives` (that folder does not exist (custom drive `A:`))
3. Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network. To try to identify the and resolve network problems, click the `Diagnose` button. (reason)
4. `Error code: 0x80070043`

   `The network name cannot be found.` (error code and error reason)

Anyways, If the dialog or dialogs are shown, and the error - if this is a mistake, see this support and realize this on Microsoft here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/map-a-network-drive-in-windows-29ce55d1-34e3-a7e2-4801-131475f9557d.

Comment: And what if you use the IP? Check for name collisions

Comment: There is name collision [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_collision) - my IPv6 address is `2603:9000:6e00:4f4e:2948:df08:dab0:b670`.